# IntelliJ not using external Jar's if not added via Maven when running JSF application?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, dependencies

I have a very simple line of code that is called from an .xhtml file ( in a JSF 2.0 project )  which looks like:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
}catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So in my C:\ folder I have the file: **mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin**. I have added this jar as an extenral jar in IntelliJ Idea 12.

When I start my application like this, I get the "Class not found exception." However, when I add this dependency to my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

I get no exception and class is loaded fine.

Here is a screenshot: [image]

The jar file I underlined with green is the Jar added externally from **File -> Project Structure -> Libraries **

The one I underlined with red is the jar file that is downloaded by maven.

My question is: Why do I get the Class not found exception, although I have added the Jar externally?

In case I require a Jar file that I will not be able to download via maven, what am I supposed to do?

**One extra information:** I created a sample Java project with one class only, and I added this external Jar file with the method I explained above. No maven, no tomcat, nothing. Just a simple main method. I ran this same code, and it worked fine. So it has to have something to do with IntelliJ and one or more of:

- Maven
- Tomcat ( Deploying a War file )
- Maven and Tomcat?

**Edit: When I add the external Jar only** and try importing a class from com.mysql.jdbc... IntelliJ IDEA does not come up with any warnings / errors. It finds the class, however after the deployment, it seems like the Class can not be found anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The webapp is deployed and run on tomcat. Tomcat doesn't care about the jars in the IntelliJ source project. What matters to tomcat is the set of jar files under the WEB-INF/lib directory of the deployed webapp. Only those jars are in the classpath of the webapp.

I don't know very well how IntelliJ builds and deploys webapps, especially when Maven is in the picture. But I'd guess that it only deploys the jars that are in the compile and runtime scopes of the Maven project. For an external jar, it's probably possible to configure the IntelliJ project in order to include it in the built and deployed archive.

But anyway, if you use Maven, you must be able to build your war without using IntelliJ. That's the whole point of a build tool: it's used to build a project without an IDE. So all the necessary jars must be known by Maven. So the jar, if not available in the Maven central, should be added to your own local Maven repo (at least), or to your company's private repo.